# Not return to my app after successful signup in Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have used `facebook-android-sdk:4.12.0`.When I login from my app,Facebook native app launched and displays username,password screen. Here I try to sign Up on Facebook,it asks details and sign up successfully and also displays my home page. But If I **click on device back button,it does not goes to my App again**. Instead of that, it closes the app.Again I launch my app from launcher,the same Facebook home screen displays,but not go to my app.

This issue occurs only in **Samsung S4 device**.How to resolve this issue.Is it any thing I need to do?

**LoginFragment.java**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


        facebookLoginButton = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                if (loginResult.getAccessToken() != null) {
                    AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());

                    mListener.onFacebookLoginSuccess();
                } else {
                    //Facebook access token not available.
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.login_cancelled_please_try_again), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.login_cancelled_please_try_again), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        facebookLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginFragment.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoginFragment.OnLoginFragmentListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookLoginSuccess() {
        // Launch Main Activity.
        launchMainActivity();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post code here

Comment: Have you returned anything onActivityResult of the activity.@Ramprasad.

Comment: @mdDroid I have added code on my question

Comment: @CrazyAndroid i implemented onActivityResult inside my fragment,not implemented in my Activity.See my code above.

Comment: where are you checking if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) in your onActivityForResult@Ramprasad.

Comment: @CrazyAndroid no I am not checking it

Answer (score 0):

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginFragment.this.. 
//?! probably problem here, must be activity context getActivity()
```

implement all this in activity class and then call public method for loginning from your fragment

```
((YourActivity)getActivity()).yourLoginMethod();
```

but also check this:

in extended Application class:

```
private static AccessTokenTracker mAccessTokenTracker;
```

oncreate:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(mContext);
mAccessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                    AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                    AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                if(currentAccessToken != null){
                    SettingsService.settings.facebookToken = currentAccessToken.getToken();
                    SettingsService.saveSettings();
                }

            }
        };
```

in manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />


<meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

for usability settings:

```
public class SettingsModel {
    public String facebookToken = "";
    //....
}
```

and class:

```
public class SettingsService {

    private static String KEY = "yourDesiredKey";
    private static Context mContext;

    public static SettingsModel settings;

    public SettingsService(){
        mContext = LastGrabApplication.getLastGrabContext();
        //if(settings == null){
        settings = getSettings();
        //}
    }

    public static void saveSettings(){
        if(settings == null){
            settings = new SettingsModel();
        }
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext
                .getSharedPreferences(KEY, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonSettings = gson.toJson(settings);
        editor.putString("settings", jsonSettings );
        editor.commit();
        settings = getSettings();
    }


    public static SettingsModel getSettings() {
        SharedPreferences editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences(KEY,
                Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        try{
            String jsonSettings = editor.getString("settings","settings");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            settings = gson.fromJson(jsonSettings, SettingsModel.class);
        }catch (Exception e){
            settings = new SettingsModel();
        }

        return settings;
    }


}
```

please make attention implement IN ACTIVITY:

```
public void loginWithFacebook(){
    try{
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

and then call from fragment:

```
((YourActivity)getActivity()).loginWithFacebook();
```

Comment: this is custom class to keep updated Facebook token (i serialize it to json and save on storage in on saveSettings) - this is useful to keep token always updated and saved.

Comment: I updated answer with that class - hope will be clear ))

Comment: No luck.Above answer not works,again same thing occurs. But If I logout and click on back,goes to app again. Is it any problem with the Facebook native app version installed on device?

Comment: are you sure you implementing onActivityResult and call to Login in Activity? and you pass right context in : LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends")); // must be "this" when implementing from Activity

Comment: yes I implemented onActivityResult,registerCallback in Activity. On Fragment on button click event called like                     LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(getActivity(), Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends")); But still not works ?

Comment: updated answer. Please implement like i described at the bottom of answer.